# Python: ImportError : Can not import modul named

Tags: python

i'm working with python 3.7 and I try to develop an ecommerce api with flask and many other flask extension but when i want to initiate for example my migration to create databse i got an import error I have a such great problem with import in python that i always get frustrated with that, is someone can tell what i dit wrong? I put below the architecture of my root directory and the factory.py file where in i tried to import some variables

[image]

and I put below the stack trace i got when I try to run `python shared/manage.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "shared/manage.py", line 1, in <module>
    from factory import create_app
ImportError: No module named factory
```

I this is my factory.py file

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_mail import Mail
from config import Config
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_migrate import Migrate
import os
db = SQLAlchemy()
mail = Mail()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
cors = CORS()
migrate = Migrate()


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, root_path=os.getcwd())
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    db.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    cors.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)

    from admin.views import admin
    from users.views import users
    from orders.views import order
    from products.views import product
    from main.views import main
    from adresses.views import adresse
    from comments.views import comment
    from car.views import carmanager
    from categories.views import category
    from quote.views import quote
    from message.views import message
    from wishlist.views import wishlist

    with app.app_context():
        app.register_blueprint(admin)
        app.register_blueprint(order)
        app.register_blueprint(users)
        app.register_blueprint(product)
        app.register_blueprint(main)
        app.register_blueprint(adresse)
        app.register_blueprint(comment)
        app.register_blueprint(carmanager)
        app.register_blueprint(category)
        app.register_blueprint(quote)
        app.register_blueprint(message)
        app.register_blueprint(wishlist)

    return app
```

if someone can help it will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not lie in `factory.py`. You are trying to import a file one level higher in the directory tree. As such, your import statement should be:

```
from ..factory import create_app
```

Comment: i tried this but it raise another error telling me ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Comment: @BryanBouka add a `__init__.py` file in the same directory as `factory.py`. It can be empty.